# Installing networkx v2.4 for python3.7 via anaconda on Windows 10

Tags: installation, conda, networkx, python-3.7, anaconda3

I installed Anaconda3 (version 2019.10-Windowsx86_64) on my PC last week. It comes with networkx v2.3, but I would like to upgrade to v2.4, which should be available on Anaconda according to `conda search` and [Anaconda's website](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/networkx).

I first tried the Anaconda navigator, but can't get it to work. It indicates that  networkx can be updated. However, when I click `Apply` the navigator spends a bit of time "solving package specifications" and then gives me the empty pop-up shown below.

[image]

I also tried using conda prompt. Using `conda install networkx`, `conda update networkx`, `conda install -c anaconda networkx` does not result in v2.4 being installed. I also tried `conda install networkx=2.4`, which takes forever and then reports a very long list of package conflicts. I find this confusing because I *just* installed Anaconda and haven't tampered with any configs yet.

Grateful for any help on understanding what is going on and how I can attempt to fix it!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip install --upgrade networkx
```

Comment: this is horrible advice, trying to upgrade a conda installed package with pip is a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried conda install networkx=2.4, which takes forever and then reports a very long list of package conflicts.

This is the key here. `anaconda` comes with many packages pre-installed and some of these might depend on `networkx==2.3` since they might not be compatible with the newest version.

What you can do is create a new environment that has the required version of `networkx`:

```
conda create -n myenv python=<your desired python version> networkx==2.4
```

which will create a new environment where you can only install the packages that you need and make sure that `networkx==0.24` is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in jupyter notebook in case you are working on jupyter notebook.

```
!pip install networkx==2.4
```

I had 2.5 v installed. But something wasn't working and had to degrade it to 2.4 and above method worked.